# Execute a task in Maven before packaging

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3

I don't understand how to run a task in Maven, before packaging.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        [...]
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="****** TEST *****" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I run `mvn clean package`, it doesn't get executed. How can I have this task executed? I'm using maven 3.0.5, if it matters.

** UPDATE: **

Adding `id` and `goal` as suggested, solved the problem from the command line.

```
<id>my-generate-sources</id>
<goals>
    <goal>run</goal>
</goals>
```

To fix Eclipse error, I've configured lifecyleMappingMetadata, within the build section:

```
<build>
...
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Comment: I don't think the execution `<id/>` is the issue. What kind of packaging type does your project use? If it's `pom`, this won't work. Maybe you could paste your whole pom.xml...?

Comment: `<packaging>war</packaging>`. http://pastebin.com/VY6uGK5z

Comment: Try setting the `<phase>` to `initialize` or `process-resources`.

Comment: `generate-sources`, `initialize` and `process-resources` phases all work from command line, my next problem was about `m2e` plugin, now solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `<goals>` tag (and adding an `<id>` tag is also strongly encouraged though not required if you only have one `<execution>` for the plugin), e.g.

```
      ...
      <execution>
        <id>print-something</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <echo message="****** TEST *****" />
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      ...
```

Comment: with goal `run` Eclipse tells me: "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (execution: my-generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)", but from the command line it works... hmm.. progress

Comment: @stivlo that is because Eclipse needs some additional metadata sop that it is aware of any "crazy" stuff that is going on and can decide to re-run your plugin as needed. You can either ignore that or investigate adding the required lifecycle information to your pom

Comment: @StephenConnolly, thanks, I tried, but still no joy, see the question update

Comment: Success, the configuration was not in the right place, I've added now inside the build - pluginManagement - plugins and it works, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an execution id:

```
<execution>
     <phase>generate-sources</phase>
     <id>my-generate-sources</id>
     <configuration>
         <tasks>
            <echo message="****** TEST *****" />
        </tasks>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
      <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot the run goal, as Guillame said. Eclipse maven integration is one of the worse things I have ever seen. The way we were running it is exclusivley via maven command line, and that is what I would recommend. You can still run it from eclipse like this:

- create a new empty project
- create mvn-clean-package.launch file in it

The file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ProgramLaunchConfigurationType">
        <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.ATTR_REFRESH_SCOPE" value="${resource}"/>
        <listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.favoriteGroups">
        <listEntry value="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.launchGroup"/>
        </listAttribute>
        <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_LAUNCH_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_SCOPE" value="${none}"/>
        <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_LOCATION" value="/usr/bin/mvn"/>
        <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TOOL_ARGUMENTS" value="clean package -DskipTests=true -U"/>
        <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="${selected_resource_loc}"/>
   </launchConfiguration>
```

As long as this project is opened in your workspace, you can select any other project folder that contains `pom.xml` and select your mvn-clean-package command from the external tools button:

[image]

This will run:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests=true -U
```

from the selected folder. You can see the output in Eclipse console window.

The external tools are also accessible also from the Run menu. I suppose that there is method to achieve this through Eclipse UI, but I didn't use Eclipse long enough to find that out.

Comment: With just the `id`, it still doesn't get executed `goal` `run`, as suggested by Guillaume works, but Eclipse complains (see the other comment).

Comment: I've managed to get m2e working, see my question update. Thank you for your help.